# magento show tab if content exists

Tags: magento, tabs, product

i'm using the tab.phtml from the modern theme to create product tabs, however i've switched this to using jquery and jquery-ui as i needed to link to a tab directly.

So in a nut shell the code is pretty much the same as the one found in the modern theme.

```
    <div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($this->getTabs() as $_index => $_tab): ?>
        <?php if($this->getChildHtml($_tab['alias'])): ?>
            <li class="<?php echo !$_index?' active first':(($_index==count($this->getTabs())-1)?' last':'')?>"><a href="#<?php echo $_tab['alias'] ?>"><?php echo $_tab['title']?></a></li>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<div class="clearer"></div>
<?php foreach ($this->getTabs() as $_index => $_tab): ?>
    <?php if($this->getChildHtml($_tab['alias'])): ?>
        <div class="product-tabs-content" id="<?php echo $_tab['alias'] ?>"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml($_tab['alias']) ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

and i'm adding the custom tabs using the same method under catalog.xml:

```
<action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>how-to-use</alias><title>How to Use</title><block>catalog/product_view</block><template>catalog/product/view/how-to-use.phtml</template></action>
```

however i've noticed that the tab 'upsells' only appears when there are upsell products assigned. I'm wanting to use this same functionality to display a custom product attribute if there is content to display.

So what i'm asking is how does the upsell detect that there are no products assigned so no tab is displayed so i can do this for my custom tab. my custom tab phtml file looks like this:

```
<?php $_howtouse = $this->getProduct()->getHowToUse(); ?>
<?php if ($_howtouse): ?>
<div class="std">
    <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), $_howtouse, 'howtouse') ?>
</div>
```

any help greaty received thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out i had 1 line above my:

```
<?php $_howtouse = $this->getProduct()->getHowToUse(); ?>
```

which meant it registered as there being some content all be it white space.
got rid of the whitespace it now works.

Answer (score 0):

The first line of code in upsell.phtml controls the appearance:

```
<?php if(count($this->getItemCollection()->getItems())): ?>
```

I am speculating your code is simply evaluating to true and always showing that section. What is your output from $this->getProduct()->getHowToUse() ?

Comment: it's just a text area, i simply want to show the tab if there is some content in there but something like this doesn't work:                                                                     $this->getProduct()->getHowToUse() != ''